# Programming for matrix manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, matrix

I want to write a programme which operates on `nd x nd` matrices. The programme looks the matrix as a `n x n` block matrix where each block is of size `d x d`. It applies a map, say `f` on each of these `d x d` matrices and output the global matrix. As a sample, I am giving a code, which is on `64 x 64` matrices and the map is applying on the `4 x 4` block matrices.

```
Big[A0_] :=
 Module[{A = A0},
  For[i = 1, i <= 64, i = i + 4,
   For[j = 1, j <= 64, j = j + 4,
    A[[i ;; i + 3, j ;; j + 3]] = f[A[[i ;; i + 3, j ;; j + 3]]]
    ]
   ];
  A]
```

I then used this simple code to define the function `f` and a list `L`.

```
X = Table[Subscript[x, i, j], {i, 64}, {j, 64}];
L = {a, b, c, d}
f[X_] := DiagonalMatrix[(m + 1)*Diagonal[X] + 
     L*RotateLeft[Diagonal[X], 1]];
Big[X] // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

I think, I am forcing Mathematica to do some unwanted calculations (in those `for` loops), which do not reflect in the output matrix and are unnecessary. So question, is it possible to make it simpler.

Further, I am putting the dimension of the larger matrix by hand (here it is `64`) and also the break up of `n x d` block matrices. If I want to apply this map on dimension `4` to a matrix of order `16 x 16`, viewed as a `4 x 4` block matrix, we need to access the main programme and change the limits accordingly by hand.  Can it be done in a better way, so that I can write only one programme for any arbitrary dimensions.

Note: My initial programme was more complicated. I just now realised that It can be simplified. So I have modified accordingly.

Comment: Could you add some minimal examples of desired input/output?

Comment: I used this matrix for checking. 


`X = Table[Subscript[x, i, j], {i, 64}, {j, 64}];
Big[X,m,p,q,r,s]`


This is because of the program which we have written earlier. This makes a `64 x 64` matrix, which can be seen as a `16 x 16` block matrix, where each block is a diagonal matrix. 


Of course, my actual program is to write a more complicated operation instead of the simple one. This is just a test cast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to demonstrate this with a smaller matrix to enable us to more readily view the results.

```
A0 = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 8}, {j, 8}];
A0//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Step 1**. Partition A0 into 4x4 blocks

```
A0byBlock = Partition[A0, {4, 4}];
A0byBlock // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Step 2**. Map f onto A0 at level 2

```
A0out = Map[f, A0byBlock, {2}];
A0out // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Step 3**. Repack A0out into 8x8 matrix

```
A0outF = ArrayFlatten[A0out];
A0outF // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now these steps can be bundled up into a function. I will define
the function name to be *big2* as a substitute for your *Big* (I use
small letters for user defined function names)

```
big2[A0_, f_, nd_] := Module[
  {
   A0byBlock,
   A0Out
   },

  A0byBlock = Partition[A0, {nd, nd}];
  A0Out = Map[f, A0byBlock, {2}];

  (* The output is given by flattening A0out *)
  ArrayFlatten[A0out]
  ]
```

I have tested this on X (your 64x64 matrix) and it worked fine.

Comment: `ArrayFlatten[]` is quite useful for your third step.

Comment: @Guess who it is - Nice tip. I was unfamiliar with ArrayFlatten. I have modified the answer to use your suggestion.